# MD5 Inconsistent between C# and golang

Tags: c#, cryptography, go, md5

I am attempting to port an algorithm from C# to go. One step I need is to take the md5 of an array of bytes. I cannot seem to get a consistent hash between C# and go implementations.

In C# I can do: `new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(new byte[] { 5 }))`

and I get `[139 182 193 120 56 100 63 150 145 204 106 77 230 197 23 9]`

In go: `md5.New().Sum([]byte{5})`

yields: `[5 212 29 140 217 143 0 178 4 233 128 9 152 236 248 66 126]`

Am I doing something wrond, or are the implementations actually different. I need to be able to replicate the C# behavior on the go side.

I have some fiddles available for [go](http://play.golang.org/p/1-PjWEJuG-) and [c#](http://dotnetfiddle.net/VgusZr) if you want to check my entire implementation.

Comment: I just noticed that whatever value you put in byte{}, it's always the first digit in the result. Wierd.

Comment: This will do the trick: http://play.golang.org/p/gWRFTFDx80

Comment: Actually, in this case this the form you want to use: https://play.golang.org/p/nPiKoGYmHF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misusing the input to the Sum function. The input parameter to sum is used to store the output, not as input to hash. Use `md5.Sum` directly (which behaves as you want) or write to the returned Hash object as demonstrated in the example: http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/md5/#example_New

Comment: One of the problems I am having is that I am hashing a particular byte array, not a string. Every example uses `io.WriteString`. I could do `io.WriteString(h,string(myBytes))`, but I am not sure that will work as I want it to.

Comment: @captncraig, `h.Write(myBytes)`. http://play.golang.org/p/Uo8sMvtm64 Take another stroll through the docs.

Comment: Very interesting. In what situation would I want to pass a non-nil value to the Sum function? Why does that parameter exist?

Comment: @captncraig if you want to reuse the same buffer over and over (because you are computing many hashes but only need the most recent) this saves substantially on allocation and garbage collection.

Comment: This is answer is incorrect; it is proper to pass a byte slice of the data for which you would like to calculate an md5 checksum. Please examine the runnable example example at https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/md5/#example_Sum. See also the correct answer by @seong, below.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
fmt.Println(md5.Sum([]byte{5}))
```

For your second question in your comment to Evan:

`hash.Hash` implements the `io.Writer`. So you can always do:

```
h := md5.New()
h.Write([]byte{5})
```

Have a look at the [hash.Hash interface](http://golang.org/pkg/hash/#Hash)