# Golang md5 Write vs Sum - why different outputs?

Tags: go, md5

Can anyone explain why these methods produce two different output values? It isn't clear from the md5 docs.

```
import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
)

func GetMD5HashWithWrite(text string) string {
    hasher := md5.New()
    hasher.Write([]byte(text))
    return hex.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil))
}

func GetMD5HashWithSum(text string) string {
    hasher := md5.New()
    return hex.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum([]byte(text)))
}
```

See example: https://play.golang.org/p/Fy7KgfCvXc

Comment: I wouldn't call it an exact duplicate, but the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765185/md5-inconsistent-between-c-sharp-and-golang applies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument to the Sum function is not input, but a location to store the output. It is technically possible to Sum into a fixed byte array without needing to allocate. You must use `Write` to provide input to the hash function.

Or use `md5.Sum()` directly:

```
func GetMD5HashWithSum(text string) string {
    hash := md5.Sum([]byte(text))
    return hex.EncodeToString(hash[:]) 
}
```

Comment: I think the documentation on md5.Sum is wrong, since the doc comment on hash.Sum is "Sum appends the current hash to b and returns the resulting slice. It does not change the underlying hash state." which is what does happen. If you call `fmt.Println(string(hasher.Sum([]byte(text))))` you get `This is a test��ُ��� ���B~` which is: `5468697320697320612074657374 d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` or, the value of `text` with the hash of an empty string (`d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`) appended.

Comment: `md5.Sum` hashes the input and returns a new array of bytes. `hasher.Sum` appends the output to the array you pass in, but does not look at the input at all.

Comment: If you never write to the hasher, then you will get the hash of an empty string, correct.

Comment: That's not what the code says: https://golang.org/src/crypto/md5/md5.go Look at the Sum method - it's not actually doing anything to the hash, you need to call Write to add bytes to the hash. That's why I say it's a doc bug - the documentation itself is wrong, the code isn't.

Comment: By "It does not change the underlying hash state." they are referring to the members of the `digest` struct which are only changes on Write. I agree the docs are a bit confusing, as I've had the same issue myself. But md5.Sum and hash.Sum do different things. I believe the docs are technically correct.

Comment: Nevermind - found the difference. `md5.Sum` (the function not bound to anything) will return the checksum. However, a variable of somemd5.Sum() (that is a Hasher) will return the concatenated bytes+hash. That is some weird packaging.

Comment: yeah, the package func is really a convenience feature, but the naming confuses things.

Answer (score 5):

I was mixing up hasher.Sum() with md5.Sum(). These do produce equivalent outputs.

```
func GetMD5HashWithWrite(text string) []byte {
    hasher := md5.New()
    hasher.Write([]byte(text))
    return hasher.Sum(nil)
}

func GetMD5HashWithSum(text string) [16]byte {
    return md5.Sum([]byte(text))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/fpE5ztnh5U